# Tomcat - display Image inside of WEB-INF

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I am currently developing a JSP/Servlet application and dont want private pictures to be accessible by other users that dont own them.

My problem is that users can access assets by simply rewriting paths in their html viewer, thats why I had to put the pictures into the `WEB-INF` Folder, to not make them accessible from the outside.

the pictures are located in `/tomcat/myProject/ROOT/WEB-INF/Users/%userName%/`

But now that the images are inside of WEB-INF I cant load them with my servlet.

Anybody knows how to access the picture, save it in a session attribute and only make them visible to the user that requested the JSP?

Edit:
I took Kaleb Brasee's code and inserted it into my method:

```
@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ...
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(profilePicturePath));
    OutputStream responseStream = response.getOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(image, "JPEG", responseStream);
    //session.setAttribute("profilepicture", PLACEHOLDER);  //PLACEHOLDER should be replaced by the actual Image, but I dont know how to do this
    //response.sendRedirect("/Index"); //doesnt get executed, because ImageIO.write(...) already commits a response before this line of code is reached
}
```

When executed, the code above will show a html page with a `img`tag containing the image from the `WEB-INF`folder, but nothing else.

This is not the desired behaviour, I need to save the `ImageIO.write(...)` output as a session attribute, so I can insert it into a specific place inside of  my `/Index` JSP Page.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a servlet that takes an image ID as a request parameter.  If the user has authorization to view file then write it to the output stream, otherwise return an HTTP error response.

The [ImageIO.write](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write(java.awt.image.RenderedImage,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File)) method is useful for writing a loaded image to a HttpServletResponse OutputStream.

I have used some code before that loads a PNG and writes it out to a response as follows:

```
response.setContentType("image/png");
BufferedImage image = generateImage(); // my custom method to create an image
OutputStream responseStream = response.getOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", responseStream);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, gonna look into it now

Comment: Alright the image seems to load now, but takes up the whole html document, do you know by any chance how to save the picture as a session attribute?

Comment: You can set anything as a session attribute via `request.getSession().setAttribute()`.  However, storing something as large as an image in sessions is problematic as an application scales up because it will use up a lot of RAM.

Comment: hey Kaleb Brasee, thanks for the help so far, I tried to solve the problem for a few more hours now, but still cant get it to work. I updated my original post, can you maybe look into it?

Comment: Have you considered making a separate servlet to display the image, then referencing that servlet from your index JSP file?  For example, creating a ImageServlet.java class, setting it up as `/image` mapping in your web.xml, then having your main index.jsp use a `<img src="/image?id=<c:out value="${imageId}" />" />` tag.